# Create user profiles/accounts using core data

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, core-data, data-modeling

I'm creating an app that has the feature of adding two profiles/accounts. Each profile will have data assosiated with it that i'm currently managing with core data. 
My CD model simply has two entities, "Baby" which has a 'birthday' and 'name', "Photo" which just has Binary data to store the photo.
The data will consist of about 100 to 200 photos with associated text and date values.

I have two questions about how I should go about this:

1. With the amount of data i'm potentially going to have, is core data the way ahead. If its not then whats my best option.
2. Could you give me a little hint as to how I should go about creating and managing the user profiles/accounts. Like whats the best way to find out if a profile exists and then show it rather than showing a plus button?

Any help would be great, even if its just to get me off in the right direction.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core Data is really a way for you, it works perfectly with even much much bigger amounts of data.

If i understand you right, and the profiles are instances of **Baby** entity, you could just make a fetch of that entity and count the number of objects—if it is only one–show add button.
If there is other way of holding those two accounts, make it a bit more clear, please.

Comment: So core data is the way ahead, nice one. I like the idea of doing a fetch and counting the objects. Cheers mate.